# java8 aggregate object converter

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have this aggregate converter:

```
public O convert() {
    output = getOutput();

    final List<GenericConverterBase> converters = getConverters();

    for (GenericConverterBase converterBase : converters) {
        output = (O) Optional.ofNullable(converterBase.getInput()).map(converterBase::apply).orElse(output);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Basically, the *getConverters()* return a list of converters that have a concrete implementation of the apply in with they fill a common kind of object (let's say OutputDTO).

This works, however I have 2 issues:

1. Is it possibile to transform for each loop using a java 8 functional method?

Premise: Actually the output is filled with new properties and keep the old ones, i.e. the second time the loop call the *converter.apply()* the output will be a result of the second and the previous one.

2. I needed to cast to (O) within the loop, otherwise java doesn't compile because it say "required O, found Object". By applying the cast (O) I solved the issue, btw compiler warn me of the "unchecked cast". Any chance to solve in other way ?

Comment: Question: Why don't you choose the last element from `converters` to assign it(after mapping) to the `output` variable? **What is the iteration even required for?** It would be worth sharing the implementations relevant to the question for the classes `GenericConverterBase` and `O` (not assuming it to be a generic here).

Comment: That's probably because he wants to "not touch" the output if the `input` is null

Comment: @m.antkowicz that doesn’t explain anything. Searching for the last occurrence of a non-`null` input has the same effect, but does much less work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use stream like this, to fetch inputs and filter them out before processing

```
output = getOutput();
emptyIfNull(getConverters())
    .stream()
    .map(GenericConverterBase::getInput)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .forEach(input -> output = input.apply(output)); // here I suppose you will need to provide casting to O
return output;
```

About casting - the question is what your `apply` method is returning - if `Object` you must cast, if not you can make converters generic, operating on the same type of O super class/interface and infer this type to the `convert` method

Comment: There is no need for inserting a questionable `emptyIfNull(…)` that wasn’t in the original code. Besides that, this code only works if `output` is a field, i.e. not a local variable. Since this is repeatedly overwriting `output`, which boils down to using the last occurrence, a clean solution would be `output = getConverters() .stream().map(GenericConverterBase::getInput).filter(Objects::nonNull).map(converterBase ::apply).reduce((a,b) -> b) .orElse(getOutput());`